# mongodb index strategy for range query with different fields

Tags: mongodb, indexing, nosql

Almost all my documents include 2 fields, **start** timestamp and **final** timestamp. And in each query, I need to retrieve elements which are in selected period of time. so **start** should be after selected value and **final** should be before selected timestamp.

query looks like

```
db.collection.find({start:{$gt:DateTime(...)}, final:{$lt:DateTime(...)}})
```

So what is the best indexing strategy for that scenario?

---

By the way, which is better for performance - to store date as datetimes or as unix timestamps, which is long value itself

Answer (score 17):

To add a little more to [baloo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330777/baloo)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15601978).

On the time-stamp vs. long issue. Generally the MongoDB server will not see a difference. The BSON encoding length is the same (64 bits). You may see a performance different on the client side depending on the driver's encoding.  As an example, on the Java side a using the 10gen driver a time-stamp is rendered as `Date` that is a lot heavier than `Long`. There are [drivers](http://www.allanbank.com/mongodb-async-driver/) that try to avoid that overhead.

The other issue is that you will see a performance improvement if you close the range for the first field of the index. So if you use the index suggested by [baloo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330777/baloo):

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({start: 1, final: 1})
```

The query will perform (potentially much) better if it is:

```
db.collection.find({start:{$gt:DateTime(...),$lt:DateTime(...)}, 
                    final:{$lt:DateTime(...)}})
```

Conceptually, if you think of the indexes as a a tree the closed range limits both sides of the tree instead of just one side. Without the closed range the server has to "check" all of the entries with a `start` greater than the time stamp provided since it does not know of the relation between `start` and `final`.

You may even find that that the query performance is no better using a single field index like:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({start: 1})
```

Most of the savings is from the first field's pruning. The case where this will not be the case is when the query is covered by the index or the ordering/sort for the results can be derived from the index.

Comment: Great notice about upper limit for first element. It's very natural and could affect performance much. =) But still hesitating between single field and composite index. Think some experiments needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Compound index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#index-type-compound) in order to create an index for multiple fields.

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({start: 1, final: 1})
```

Compare different queries and indexes by using [explain()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain/) to get the most out of your database

Comment: Yes, I know about composit index. The only thing i'm afraid in that case it will be no advantages for composite query across single field query. But I don't know for sure. Think some experiments needed.

Comment: As long as the single field is the first field in the composite index you're good to go