# Where does the extra "nscanned" comes from in this .explain()?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of bookings. Every document has these fields:

```
_id: ObjectID, 
client: ObjectID // A reference to the "owner" of the service. 
start: nr, 
end nr
```

I insert 15 dummy document (with the same id on client). the first five start at `1` and ends at `2`, the next five starts at `3`and ends at `4`, the last five starts at `5`and ends at `6`.

I then create the following index: `db.bookings.ensureIndex({client: 1, start: 1, end: 1})`

For these queries:

```
db.bookings.find({client: anID, start: {$gte: 1}}).explain()
db.bookings.find({client: anID, start: {$gte: 3}}).explain()
db.bookings.find({client: anID, start: {$gte: 5}}).explain()
```

I get the these expected results in order:

```
"n": 15, "nscannedObjects": 15, "scanned": 15
"n": 10, "nscannedObjects": 10, "scanned": 10
"n": 5, "nscannedObjects": 5, "scanned": 5
```

Which is expected and totaly fine.

But when doing these queries:

```
db.bookings.find({client: anID, start: {$gte: 1}, end: {$lte: 2}}).explain()
db.bookings.find({client: anID, start: {$gte: 3}, end: {$lte: 4}}).explain()
db.bookings.find({client: anID, start: {$gte: 5}, end: {$lte: 6}}).explain()
```

I get these confusing results in order:

```
"n": 5, "nscannedObjects": 5, "scanned": 7
"n": 5, "nscannedObjects": 5, "scanned": 6
"n": 5, "nscannedObjects": 5, "scanned": 5
```

Why do I get extra (5 is expected) scanned documents in the first two queries? Is there something wrong in my index or query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nscanned` count can be higher than the `nscannedObjects` count because MongoDB scanned more than one index entry for a particular object/document and then de-duplicated.  This is actually covered as part of the [explain example](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) in the docs.  With compound keys, it can also be the case that the index entry is scanned because it matches on the leftmost field (for example) but because it doesn't match on one of the other fields, the document is skipped and not scanned.

There is an [excellent post here](http://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/) with visuals of the `btree` traversal to help understand how this can happen.

As an aside, the new version of explain in version 3.0 will replace these fields with `totalKeysExamined` and `totalDocsExamined`.  They represent the same thing, but the names are a little more indicative of what they actually represent.

Comment: Ok. It there some kind of rule of thumb when `nscanned` are "to much" in comparison with `nscannedObjects`? Or can this differ alot in certain queries and still be correct?

Comment: well, it's a very basic measure of the efficiency of the query - if it diverges then you may need to rethink the order of the compound index, or use a different index, but as a rule of thumb I wouldn't worry about 10% differences (given larger values, a 1 doc difference for 5 `nscanned` is not something to worry about usually).  I updated the answer with a post that it took me a while to find that does an excellent job explaining this.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of querying on two ranges without relation, like I do above. (start & end) I found [this great tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601933/mongodb-index-strategy-for-range-query-with-different-fields/15603019#15603019) about "closing" the first range in the query. A query will perform potetially much better with a closed first range.