# How to find documents having a query-value within the range of two key-values

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geospatial, compound-index

I'm analyzing texts. Those texts have annotations (e.g. "chapter", "scenery", ...). Those annotations are in my MongoDB collection `annotations`, e.g.

```
{
  start: 1,
  stop: 10000,
  type: chapter,
  details: {
    number: 1,
    title: "Where it all began"
  }
},
{
  start: 10001,
  stop: 20000,
  type: chapter,
  details: {
    number: 2,
    title: "Lovers"
  }
},
{
  start: 1,
  stop: 5000,
  type: scenery,
  details: {
    descr: "castle"
  }
},
{
  start: 5001,
  stop: 15000,
  type: scenery,
  details: {
    descr: "forest"
  }
}
```

**Challenge 1**: For a given position in the text, I'd like find all annotations. For example querying for character `1234` should tell me, that

- it is within chapter one
- it takes place in the castle

**Challenge 2**: I also like to query for ranges. For example querying for characters form `9800 to 10101` should tell me, that it touches `chapter 1`, `chapter 2` and the `scenery forest`.

**Challenge 3**: Comparable to *challenge 2* I'd like to match only those annotations that are completely covered by the query-range. For example querying for characters form `9800 to 30000` should only return the document `chapter 2`.

For *challenge 1* I tried to simply use `$lt` and `$gt`. e.g.:

```
db.annotations.find({start: {$lt: 1234}, stop: {$gt: 1234}});
```

But I realized, that only indexes for the key `start` is used, even if I have a compound index for `start` and `stop`. Is there a way to create more adequate indexes for the three problems I mentioned?

I shortly thought of geospatial indexes, but I haven't used them, yet. I also only need a one-dimensional version of it.

Answer (score 3):

For **Challenge 1**, the query you are using is appropriate, though you might want to use `$lte` and `$gte` to be inclusive.

```js
db.annotations.find({ "start": { "$lt": 1234 }, "stop": { "$gt": 1234 }});
```

Regarding indexes, the reason it chooses to use the index on `start` instead of the compound index has to do with the tree structure of compound indexes, which is nicely explained by Rob Moore in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15603019/1740264). Note that it can still use the compound index if you use `hint()`, but the query optimiser finds it faster to use the index on `start` and then weed out the results that don't match the range for the `stop` clause.

For **Challenge 2**, you just need to use an explicit `$or` clause to cover the cases where `stop` is within the bounds, when `start` is within the bounds and when `start` and `stop` encompass the bounds.

```js
db.annotations.find({
    "$or": [
        { "stop": { "$gte": 9800, "$lte": 10101 }},
        { "start": { "$gte": 9800, "$lte": 10101 }},
        { "start": { "$lt": 9800 }, "stop": { "$gt": 10101 }}
    ]
});
```

For **Challenge 3**, you can use a query very similar to the one in **Challenge 1**, but ensuring that the documents are completely covered by the given bounds.

```js
db.annotations.find({ "start": { "$gte": 9800 }, "stop": { "$lte": 30000 }});
```

Comment: I could not find an answer by rob moore in the link you posted (wrong link?). hint(): is mongo also using the informatin for `start` AND `stop`? or is it only using the information for the `start: {$lte: ...}`.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed the link now. I don't know if with `hint()` the optimiser will use both bits of information or just the prefix. You could try profiling both queries and see if there is any difference.