# finding the documents containing a value closest to int

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, database

Im having the following schema:

```
var lottary = new Schema({
    userid : String,
    start: Number,
    end: Number,
    time: Number,
});
```

and im writing a query that get the result of the winner.
if the rows are as follows:

```
| start | end |
|  2    |  4  |
|   5   | 99  |
| 100   | 999 |
```

and my number are 55, it would return the row with start 5, and end 99, cause 55 is between those numbers.

I know this are done with the following in MYSQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM lotto_tickets
WHERE 40 BETWEEN start AND end
```

But, how is this done within mongoose / mongodb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate, take a look at this: [How to find documents having a query-value within the range of two key-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771884/how-to-find-documents-having-a-query-value-within-the-range-of-two-key-values)

```
db.lottary.find({ "start": { "$lt": 55}, "end": { "$gt": 55}});
```

You can obviously change the number 55 to anything u want.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Mikey, haven't noticed it was "end".